# Global variables in header files

Tags: c, include, global-variables, header-files, c89

There is a header file `foo.h` that contains a global variable declaration `int i;`. This header file is being included in `one.c` and `two.c` respectively (I am aware that that's not a very good life choice, but it's not mine).

1. Does this mean that in each *.c file exist two different variables with name `i`?
2. What is the situation with declaration/definition in this example (in accordance with standard)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how

Comment: I've seen this question. That's the reason for question #2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, global variable `i` with *external linkage* will exist in both compilation units. This will create conflict error during the linking phase.

In ideal situation, `foo.h` header should contain declaration only: `extern int i;` and the actual definition `int i;` should exist only in **one** .c file.

Other alternative is to use `static int i;` in `foo.h`. This will create `i` with *internal linkage*, meaning that variable is local on each compilation unit where header is included. However, declaring `static` variables in headers is generally considered a bad practice.

Comment: Ok, so technically we have 2 `int i;`-s in each *.c file, right? What about the tentative definition aspect? As far as I understand, `int i;` will be considered a definition only if there is no other definition of it. Is this why an error will occur, or is it smth else?

Comment: Yes one `i` on each file, total of 2. You are describing situation where `int i` is defined twice in the same compilation unit. You may write `int i;int i;`, and it will only produce 1 `i`. This is  not the case here. This conflict happens later in the linking phase, when there are 2 `i`s from different compilation units.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it. Was not totally sure because the program that was performing linking (not a common linker) threw no errors.

Comment: Any kind of non-constant variable placed in a header file is considered very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

When you include the header file in another file, until they are compiled at a time i.e., they are in single translation unit, you wont get an error. But if you have to compile both the files i.e.,

gcc -c one.c two.c

Then yes, you are running into trouble.

It is nothing related to declaration/definition. Use static to have a file scope for the variable in question or change the design.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a linker error for multiple definition of variable.

Answer (score 0):

You will have  linker error.

please search "`extern`" keyword.